# PowerShell loop through a CSV column and change the values according to criteria from another CSV

Tags: powershell

I've been attempting to write a PowerShell script that loops through a CSV column and changes the old values to new values that are mapped to search criteria.

CSV1:

```
Column1       Column2
TEST ANT  =   Test Ant,
ALPHA     =   Alpha,
OMEGA     =   Omega,
```

CSV2:

```
001234-Alpha-Bravo,
TTTTTTTTTT,
DATA:TEST-(RANDOM DATA)ANT,
ere393,
OMEGA-333,
```

Basically

1. Import a CSV1 that contains search criteria in column1 mapped to approved  values in column2.
2. Import a CSV2 that contains a column of raw data.
3. Loop through column1 of search criteria.
4. For each row in CSV1, I want to determine if that string exists in one or more rows (as a whole string, or as a substring) from the raw data column in CSV2.
5. If the string exists (whole or substring), then replace the cells raw data with the approved value.
6. If there is no match, then continue to the next row.
7. Export a CSV with the new approved values and values that were not changed.

I've searched and tried many of the examples on this site, and each one seems to address a part of the problem I'm trying to solve, but not completely. A hash table seems to be the closest to a solution, but the raw data can be dynamic and can't seem to match the key to any part of the string in the raw data.

One example I've tried

```
$s = Import-Csv C:\SearchCriteriaCSV.csv

$searchCrit = $($s.Name)
$Imported = Import-Csv 'C:\ImportCSV.csv'

$Output = foreach ($i in $Imported) {
    foreach ($c in $searchCrit) {
        if ($c.Name -like "*$i*") {
            $i.Name = $c.Name
        }
    }
    $i
}

$Output
$Output | Export-Csv 'C:\ExportCSV.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Another example tried:

```
$RawNameFormatName = @{
    "ALPHA" = "Alpha";
    "OMEGA" = "Omega"
}

$csv = Import-Csv C:\ImportCSV.csv;
foreach($row in $csv) {
    $row.Name = $RawNameFormatName[$row.Name];
}

$csv | Export-Csv  "C:\ExportCSV.csv" -NoTypeInformation;
```

Exported CSV:

```
Alpha
TTTTTTTTTT
Test Ant
ere393
Omega
```

Comment: You need to be more clear about the input file(s) used as they do not appear close to any [csv specification](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). Csv files usually do no contain any equal signs (`=`), they might be used in key/value assignment but then what is use of the `Column1` and `Column2` header?

Comment: Sorry, for the lack of clarity. I'm not limited to just using a CSV, the data input can be from other sources. I'm using a CSV file, because the examples I've tried use a CSV file for data input. The data input from the first source has headers above the columns, Column1 which is the key and Column2 which is the value.